# Track Azure B2C users who tried to verify email, but don`t provided code submitted to email

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

I want to track users who clicked verify email B2C button, but do not enter code that they should receive via email. Is there any control of that button in B2C or maybe some kind of "not verified email" storage? I`m using custom templates.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Azure Monitor to determine who at least initaited a email verification but did not complete it. Enable Log Analytics through Azure Monitor https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/azure-monitor

Then use this query in log analytics:

```
AuditLogs
| where OperationName == "Verify email address" or OperationName == "Send verification email"
| summarize count() by OperationName, CorrelationId, bin(TimeGenerated, 1h)
| summarize count() by CorrelationId, TimeGenerated
| extend state = iff(count_ == 1, "Abandoned", "Completed")
| summarize dcount(CorrelationId) by TimeGenerated, state
| render timechart
```